# How do I get the screen resolution of the user within a Delphi TMS Web Core Website?

Tags: javascript, delphi, screen-resolution, tms-web-core

In FMX, I could simply use the `TScreen` class from the `FMX.Forms` unit and have a function like this:

```
function GetScreenResolution: String;
begin
  Result := Screen.Width.ToString + 'x' + Screen.Height.ToString;
end;
```

But that doesn't work in TMS Web Core. I can however do the following code which is a mix between Delphi and JavaScript:

```
function GetScreenResolution: String;
begin
  asm
    Result = screen.width + "x" + screen.height;
  end;
end;
```

The above does work, but is there a better Delphi-only way instead of mixing the two languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.screen` from the `WEB` unit:

```
function GetScreenResolution: String;
begin
  Result := String(window.screen['width']) + 'x' + String(window.screen['height']);
end;
```